# Link to next privilege: Mouse cursor is not a pointer

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, next-privilege

If I hover above the next privilege on my profile, the mouse cursor does not change to a pointer indicating a link, but to an I-beam text cursor.

See screenshot:

[image]

Seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/633961/guettli?tab=summary

Browser: Chromium   78.0.3904.70 (Offizieller Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-Bit)

Comment: It's not a bug, it's made like this, it is not a button

Comment: ... but you can click it for additional details.